# Como Hacer click a un boton web desde excel que no tiene ni id, ni name?

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

Necesito en Excel (vba) hacer una macro o robot para ingresar unos datos en una pagina web tomando como valores un listado de data (cedula y fecha) que tengo en una hoja de Excel, esos parámetros ya lo logre pasar al formulario con esta elemento "IE.Document.getElementById", pero al intentar darle click al botón que aparece para poder completar la operación que quiero veo que el botón como tal no tiene variable id o el name para poder hacer el click desde Excel.

dejo la pagina web a la que intento acceder:

https://aplicaciones.msp.gob.ec/coresalud/app.php/publico/rpis/afiliacion/consulta

---

Me sigue arrojando un error, abrí un nuevo modulo en Excel vba y ejecute el programa pero me da un error de sintaxis en la line que te resalto con asteriscos:

```vb
Sub CARGAR_DATOS_WEB()
 Dim IE As Object
 Dim allelements As Object


 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Creamos objeto internet explorer
 Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 'abrimos web
 IE.navigate "https://aplicaciones.msp.gob.ec/coresalud/app.php/publico/rpis/afiliacion/consulta"
'esperamos a que se carguen todos los elementos
 Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
 DoEvents
 Loop
'si necesitamos más tiempo lo podemos configurar aquí
 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1000"))
'localizamos el ID que hace referencia al cuadro de búsqueda
 'esto lo hacemos buscando en el código HTML de la página web
 'e igualamos el valor de la celda para realizar la búsqueda

 IE.document.getElementById("identificacion").Value = "0960413078"

 IE.document.getElementById("fechaconsulta").Value = "10-06-2017"


'también buscamos ID correspondiente al botón para buscar el valor

***IE.document.getElementsByClassName("btn-primary")[0].click();***


'hacemos visible la web.
 IE.Visible = True
 Set IE = Nothing
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: A diferencia de algunos foros en este sitio la información adicional debe agregarse a la pregunta, no publicarse como una respuesta. Por otro lado es conveniente que en la redacción de las preguntas y respuestas en este sitio vayas directo a la pregunta o la respuesta, no incluyas saludos y ni formulas de cortesía o protocolo social, para esto último está el [chat] (debes tener al menos 20 de reputación para poder participar) y otros espacios como las redes sociales o los foros. Mas detalles en [ask].

Comment: Disculpa lo tendré en cuenta

Answer (score -1, accepted):

es mi primera respuesta en español, por favor verifica en proximas ocasiones el objeto al cual te vas a referir, ya que  a veces hay tags entre el codigo que pueden cambiar la indexacion de un objeto y que al no ser visibles nos confuden un poco, en tu caso especifico cambia

esta linea

```
***IE.document.getElementsByClassName("btn-primary")[0].click();***
```

por esta

```
 IE.document.getelementsbytagname("button")(1).Click
```

recomiendo a la proxima vez realizar una iteracion con un bucle for por todos los elementos que busques en la pagina ya sean tags u objetos como tal para que puedas buscar un atributo que los haga distintos a todos y puedas manipular el objeto con una sola linea de codigo

se me olvidaba cambia

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1000"))
```

por esto

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
```

parametros: TimeValue(*horas:minutos:segundos*)

Comment: Tienes un error en el uso de mayúsculas y minúsculas en `getelementsbytagname`, por otro lado, no mencionas el motivo por el cual propones seleccionar por nombre de etiqueta en lugar de usar nombre de clase.

Comment: ruben para aclarar en vba  este metodo (getelementsbytagname) no es case sensitive asi que no es una mala practica en visual basic, por otra parte, es bueno que quien pregunta  referirse a la etiqueta dado a que hay varios componentes con la misma clase que no soportan la accion click(), por eso sugiero al usuario iterar entre los componentes por su nombre de etiqueta para elegir el que necesita.

Comment: Funciona Excelente el codigo

Answer (score 0):

Hola Marlon la forma correcta en VBA es la siguiente:

`document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary")(0).Click`

espero que te sirva.

Comment: No creo que funcione. ¿lo has probado?

Answer (score 0):

El código tiene dos errores

En lugar de

```
IE.document.getElementsByClassName("btn-primary")(0).click
```

deber ser

```
IE.document.getElementsByClassName("btn-primary")(0).Click
```

> Nótese el uso de mayúscula inicial en `Click`.

y en lugar de

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1000"))
```

deber ser

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
```

Por cierto, lo probé en Excel 2016.

Comment: Funciona Excelente

Comment: @Marlon: Gracias. Si esta es la respuesta que has encontrado más útil, por favor acéptala. Más detalles en [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien responde mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score -1):

EL botón que se muestra en esa pagina tiene la clase "btn-primary" de bootstrap

```
document.getElementsByClassName("btn-primary")[0].click();
```

Como consejo te recomiendo lo pongas en un **setTimeout** con unos 1000 milisegundos para que des tiempo a la pagina de que cargue.

Comment: Me da error de sintaxis al ejecutar la macro (vba) en esa línea de código que me indicas, ¿Qué debo hacer?

Comment: No e trabajdo con el macro de exel, pero seguramente usa un motor de IE o Edge que no soportan el ClassName por lo que dada tu situación no puedes hacer nada. Puedes intentar usando getElementsByTagName('button') pero si no funciono con ClassName dudo que funcione. Yo mismo probe ese codigo en la pagina que mencionas y funciono perfectamente, tu problema esta en que Excel no soporta los valores que deseas.

Comment: Uno de los problemas con esta respuesta es que `[0]` no corresponde a la notación de `VBA`.